# Replace character using regexp_replace after and before character

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I'm new using `REGEXP_REPLACE()`. I want to replace `0` to `'-'` digit, for example : `30000000176215001500` we get `3-176215001500`

I tried using `regexp_replace('30000000176215001500','([0])','-')`, but it changes all `0`s to `-`.

This is what I expect:

> 1. `30000001174934177910` : `3-1174934177910`
> 2. `30000000174934177910` : `3-174934177910`
> 3. `301873130520` : `3-1873130520`
> 4. `300173130520` : `3-173130520`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

```
regexp_replace(mycol,'0+','-', 1, 1)
```

Rationale: the fifth parameter, when greater than 0, specifies wich occurence should be replaced; when it is set to 0, all occurences are replaced.

Other notable changes to your original regex:

- parentheses define capturing group; since you don't need to capture, there are superfluous
- brackets define a character class; not needed since you are matching on a single character

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9c0cc161de3d2e5da34a70501a001e7e)**:

```
with a as (
    select '30000001174934177910' mycol from dual
    union all select '30000000174934177910' from dual
    union all select '301873130520' from dual
    union all select '300173130520' from dual
)
select mycol input, regexp_replace(mycol,'0+','-', 1, 1) output from a
```

```
INPUT                | OUTPUT         
:------------------- | :--------------
30000001174934177910 | 3-1174934177910
30000000174934177910 | 3-174934177910 
301873130520         | 3-1873130520   
300173130520         | 3-173130520
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right - I completely missed that.